# Receiving "Component is missing template" when migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an application with a component that rendered correctly in Vue 2.
The component looked like this in Vue2:

```
const MyComponent = Vue.component("my-comp", { 
    template: '#my-component',
    ...
})
```

I then defined my template in a separate script tag:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
    ...
</script>
```

I am now migrating this application to Vue3 and my component is now defined as follows:

```
const MyComponent = vueApp.component("my-comp", { 
    template: '#my-component',
    ...
})
```

However, I am now getting the following error:

```
vue@3:1590 [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <Anonymous onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is known as **inline-template** or **x-template**.
It has been deprecated in Vue 3 and is no longer supported.

**A possible workaround is to replace the script type `text/x-template` by `text/html`.**

Source: official [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/inline-template-attribute.html).